# How would I remap Mac CMD to CTRL keys in Blender?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I want to remap the <kbd>command</kbd> with the <kbd>control</kbd> in Blender application. I've tried using Karabiner and when I open it these are the default Blender options:

[image]

I wonder how I can add the <kbd>command</kbd>/<kbd>control</kbd> switch as well?

I've tried doing it by updating the `private.xml` file as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>For Applications</name>
            <item>
                <name>Enable at only Blender</name>
                <identifier>private.swap_command_and_control</identifier>
                <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
                <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
            </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

But it's wrong as shown here:
[image]

I want it to be appearing under the blender application item as shown below. Any advice please?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your private.xml is missing the *only* key and would swap the keys system-wide. Additionally you got the naming of the item wrong.

Here is a working private.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Enable at only Blender - custom</name>
            <item>
                <name>Swap Command and Control</name>
                <identifier>private.swap_command_and_control</identifier>
                <only>BLENDER</only>
                <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
                <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
            </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

or if you want the "For applications" to appear in the private section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>For Applications</name>
        <item>
        <name>Enable at only Blender - custom</name>
            <item>
                <name>Swap Command and Control</name>
                <identifier>private.swap_command_and_control</identifier>
                <only>BLENDER</only>
                <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
                <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

---

If you want the key mod to appear in the non-private part "For applications" you have to add it (the most inner item key including `<item>` and `</item>`) to the file: /Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Resources/include/checkbox/apps/blender.xml.

**Any Karabiner update/upgrade will remove/overwrite your mod probably**.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

  <item>
    <name>Enable at only Blender</name>

    <item>
      <name>FlipScrollWheel</name>
      <item>
        <name>Flip Horizontal and Vertical ScrollWheel at Blender</name>
        <identifier>remap.app_Blender_flipscrollwheel</identifier>
        <only>BLENDER</only>
        <autogen>
          __FlipScrollWheel__
          Option::FLIPSCROLLWHEEL_HORIZONTAL,
          Option::FLIPSCROLLWHEEL_VERTICAL,
        </autogen>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Flip Horizontal ScrollWheel at Blender</name>
        <identifier>remap.app_Blender_flipscrollwheel_horizontal</identifier>
        <only>BLENDER</only>
        <autogen>
          __FlipScrollWheel__
          Option::FLIPSCROLLWHEEL_HORIZONTAL,
        </autogen>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Flip Vertical ScrollWheel at Blender</name>
        <identifier>remap.app_Blender_flipscrollwheel_vertical</identifier>
        <only>BLENDER</only>
        <autogen>
          __FlipScrollWheel__
          Option::FLIPSCROLLWHEEL_VERTICAL,
        </autogen>
      </item>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Keys</name>
      <item>
        <name>Swap Command and Control at Blender</name>
        <identifier>private.swap_command_and_control</identifier>
        <only>BLENDER</only>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
      </item>

    </item>

  </item>

</root>
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will this create it under the blender item? I've updated my question to clarify what I want if you could please check.

Comment: @Tak No of course not. The private.xml is a key mod on a per user base and resides somewhere in your user folder. But I will update my answer to meet your needs...